# Refresh Folder in spring boot after uploading a file

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot

I upload a file using my spring boot Application in the path : `C:\Users\myPC\eclipse-workspace\myPROJECT\src\main\resources\static\files\`

The probleme is that the url : 
`http://localhost:8088/files/file_example.png` not working unless i refresh the folder `src/main/ressources/static/files` manually from Eclipse IDE.

I search in web about this probleme but i found nothing to fix it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with Eclipse, such as my case, go to Window -> Preferences and search for workspace, then check `Refresh using native hooks or polling`.

**it worked for me.**